# Powershell command to get filesystem drive names - member-access enumeration

Tags: powershell, enumeration, member-enumeration

I am trying to fetch disk free space and used space in windows 2008 R2 enterprise edition. However the command fails to get the values. This command works fine in windows 2012 version.

Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem  will fetch below details..

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider
----           ---------     --------- --------
C                  71.99        166.23 FileSystem
H                  71.99        166.23 FileSystem

(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name - get me the drive names and so I use to fetch the other details.

However the same command does not work for windows 2008 R2 enterprise edition. Any work around for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Name` relies on **[*member-access enumeration*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/), a feature that was introduced in PSv3**, whereas **Windows Server 2008 R2 ships with PSv2**.

*Member-access enumeration* means that you can access a property such as `.Name` on a *collection* (array) and have that property implicitly accessed on *each element* of that collection, with the results collected in an *array*.

**In PSv2-, you must use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet** (or its alias, `%`) instead:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | % { $_.Name } # return drive names as array
```

Comment: I have always wanted to know the name of this feature!  Thank you.

Comment: @MikeShepard, the feature is finally being officially named and properly documented, with a slightly improved name "member-_access_ enumeration" instead of just "member enumeration" - see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/8437#issuecomment-1064258293